# How to iterate time (as anargument) for a few days in bash script

Tags: shell, time, arguments

```
Input_Date=$1
Input_hour=$2

date1to5=$(date -d "$Input_Date +5 days" +%Y%m%d)
Inputdate2=$(date -d "$Input_Date" +%Y%m%d)
while [ "$Input_Date" -lt "$date1to5" ];  do
        for hr in {00..23};
        do
                touch TEST_$Inputdate2$Input_hour"_"$Input_Date$hr.txt
        done
Input_Date=$(date -d "$Input_Date + 1 day" +%Y%m%d )
done
```

I have a code which is creating files every other hour by taking as an argument . The problem is hours loops from 00 to 23 but i want to get loop from Input_hour to 5 days later until Input_hour.

Expected output is:

```
TEST_2022031506_2022031506.txt
TEST_2022031506_2022031507.txt
TEST_2022031506_2022031508.txt
TEST_2022031506_2022031509.txt
.
.
.
.
TEST_2022031506_2022031903.txt
TEST_2022031506_2022031904.txt
TEST_2022031506_2022031905.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform arithmetic operations on dates, you probably want to use [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). This is how I would do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Input_Date=$1
Input_Date_epoch=$(date -d "$Input_Date" +%s)
Input_hour=$2
nowdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)

Target=5
Target_epoch=$((Target * 86400)) # 1 day = 86400 seconds
date1toTarget=$((Input_Date_epoch + Target_epoch))

while [ "$Input_Date_epoch" -lt "$date1toTarget" ]; do
    for hr in $(seq -f %02g 0 23); do
        touch TEST_"$nowdate""$Input_hour"_"$Input_Date""$hr".txt
    done
    Input_Date_epoch=$((Input_Date_epoch + 86400)) # +1 day
    Input_Date="$(date -d @"$Input_Date_epoch" +%Y%m%d)" # +1 day
done
```

Comment: Looks good but need to Input_hour in for loop in case of "00"

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you mean, but if I understand correctly, the for loop skips the body if the `hr` is 00. In order to include 00, you can modify the for loop to use seq utility (https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq). I've updated my original answer with hopefully working implementation.

Comment: `while [ "$Input_Date_epoch" -lt "$date1toTarget" ]; do
    for hr in $(seq -f %02g $Input_hour 23); do
        touch TEST_"$nowdate""$Input_hour"_"$Input_Date""$hr".txt
    done
    Input_Date_epoch=$((Input_Date_epoch + 86400)) # +1 day
    Input_Date="$(date -d @"$Input_Date_epoch" +%Y%m%d)" # +1 day
done`
 it works like this. I modified `$Input_hour ` in case of `0` but time need to continue for second five days. I have a second while loop.

Comment: `while [ "$Input_Date_epoch" -lt "$date6to10" ]; do
    for hr in $(seq -f %02g $Input_hour 3 23); do
        touch TEST_"$nowdate""$Input_hour"_"$Input_Date""$hr".txt
    done
    Input_Date_epoch=$((Input_Date_epoch + 86400)) # +1 day
    Input_Date="$(date -d @"$Input_Date_epoch" +%Y%m%d)" # +1 day
done` it loops again from Input_hour to 23